# Как добавить несколько файлов к exe --add-data?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "py;ProgramFiles" --add-data "png;images" --add-data "csv;Data" --add-data "db;Data" --add-data "jpg;images_processing" --add-data "ui;UI_files" main.py
```

Я ввожу такую команду в консоль и мне выдаёт ошибку: **Unable to find "C:\Users\Dima\Desktop\OtherPaint\py" when adding binary and data files**

Я не понимаю, как добавить все файлы из каталога.

Comment: а вы знаете, как их потом доставать? я так и не смог. закодировал нужные в текст и засунул в программу :(

Comment: @splash58 Не знаю, с таким не сталкивался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pyinstaller в качестве аргументов параметра -add-data принимает path_to_file;directory_to_save где path_to_file это путь к произвольному файлу, а не типу файлов, и ;directory_to_save - директория, в которую будет сохранен файл, после сборки.

`--add-data` требуется добавлять к каждому файлу, который вы хотите добавить.
Пример.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "music/my_song.mp3;media_data/music" --add-data "my_img.png;media_data/images" main.py
```

Comment: Если надо всю папку добавить, то вместо конкретного файла, указывайте, например `--add-data "images;images"`.